# Flutter, reload an item in List View

Tags: flutter

This should be common but I can't find much information about this.  I have a lazy loading list with Cards to show data for each record fetched from http request. How do I refresh the data of a single record when a button or action in a Card is being clicked or done?

Structure is something like:

```
Stateful Widget
    loadData()  //http request by page loading

    Widget build
        TextButton onPressed(){loadData} 
        ListView.builder(
            itemCount: fullList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return dataCard(context, fullList, index);
        }),
```

```
dataCard(context, dl, i)
    Text(dl[i].Name)
    Text(dl[i].Price) 
    setIcon(dl[i].type)
    ...
```

```
setIcon(type)
    switch type
    case 1
        return Icon A
    case 2
        return Icon B
    ...
```

How can I detect action in dataCard or setIcon and reload the corresponding item in the list?

Comment: make sure to call setState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a function in stateful class, update the data list by index, then setState().

```
void refreshRecord(index) async{
   dataList[index].name = new value  
   setState()
}
```